# when downloading a Snap (Snapd) onto a raspberry pi, where is the snap stored in the File manager

Tags: pi-4

When I installed a snap, I don't know where to find it. Any help would be wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Is this is the solution? || https://askubuntu.com/a/917345/859552

Comment: not quite sure. I've addeed another question, which[ is probably better than this one:      https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107854/can-anyone-make-heads-or-tails-about-this

Comment: Do you want the path of a command? try: `which command` like `which minetest`.